# How can I create a pdf report from an excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, report

I want to generate a pdf report to a specific student showing all of his grades in a determined period of time. I have very little experience with python and have no idea where to start.
Thks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the library:pyxlsb to read the excel file,
and the library: PyFPDF to generate pdf files
there is many libraries not only these

after installing these libraries with pip:

```
pip install fpdf
pip install pyxlsb
```

but you need to write script to extract the data from the excel file, and also for generating the pdf file
and you can apply the same script for other student with the data excel format
greetings